# Unturned weapon modification not spawning in singleplayer

Tags: unity, modding, spawning

I've been working on my first modification for Unturned and I'm having some serious trouble doing the process due to the lack of up-to-date tutorials on modding weapons.

I've done everything I can to make it, and I was finally able to create a bundle and export the *.unity3d* file into the copied folder for my modded gun. However, when I go into Unturned and actually attempt to spawn it, nothing works.

I'm assuming it's the version of Unity that I'm using (Unity 5 2.4), even though I followed the instructions correctly while in the editor. Please help, I really need a solution, because I've been at it for weeks now and no one has been able to provide any solution.

Comment: No its compatible with unity 5 now

Comment: Sorry i meant untiy 5 2.4. And yes ive tried the latest update but turns out its not compatible at all

Comment: My apologies, im running out of options from countless amounts of research and im desperste for help

Comment: Im currently working atm, but on my lunch break soon ill do some digging (I haven't modded unturned in some) and get back to you with a Answer.

Comment: ok 21 hours later haha, may i ask how you have done the implementing it into the game? did you use the tool provided and then attempt to console spawn it with the name assigned?

Comment: Yeah I fixed a lot of issues in this matter. I was able to get in contact with mod devs and I was just highly misinformed.

Comment: If youve found a solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah the thing is it will be a whole tutorial if i do. The best i can say now is contact mod developers that are still active on steam and ask them for help.

Comment: I would write an answer with the full tutorial (As my team worked on the British weapons pack mod) But i feel the down-votes would be heavy lol, @user199845 has the best advice on this